# find matching elements in two php arrays, and then list both array elements together

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ï»¿"Product Category"
            [1] => Product Name
            [2] => Product ID
            [3] => Average Item Price
            [4] => Item Sales
            [5] => Items Sold
            [6] => Product Conversion (Sold/Views)
            [7] => Item Abandonment Rate
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => OVERALL
            [1] => -
            [2] => -
            [3] => $51.17
            [4] => $1335974.77
            [5] => 26111
            [6] => 16.25%
            [7] => 42.06%
        )



ARRAY B:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ï»¿"Content Category"
            [1] => Page Name
            [2] => Page Views
            [3] => Sessions
            [4] => Orders / Session
            [5] => Sales
            [6] => Bounce Rate
            [7] => Page Views / Session
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => OVERALL
            [1] => -
            [2] => 1017924
            [3] => 135154
            [4] => 16.57%
            [5] => $1354866.20
            [6] => 23.81%
            [7] => 7.53
        )
```

I want to combine two arrays into one... where the result will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ï»¿"Product Category"
            [1] => Product Name
            [2] => Product ID
            [3] => Average Item Price
            [4] => Item Sales
            [5] => Items Sold
            [6] => Product Conversion (Sold/Views)
            [7] => Item Abandonment Rate
            [8] => ï»¿"Content Category"
            [9] => Page Name
            [10] => Page Views
            [11] => Sessions
            [12] => Orders / Session
            [13] => Sales
            [14] => Bounce Rate
            [15] => Page Views / Session

        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => OVERALL
            [1] => -
            [2] => -
            [3] => $51.17
            [4] => $1335974.77
            [5] => 26111
            [6] => 16.25%
            [7] => 42.06%
            [8] => OVERALL
            [9] => -
            [10] => 1017924
            [11] => 135154
            [12] => 16.57%
            [13] => $1354866.20
            [14] => 23.81%
            [15] => 7.53

        )
```

I only want to output the matched arrays where the "Product Category" == "Content Category", and combine the two array elements...

I wasn't too sure if there was a predefined function for this, but I'm assuming I have to do some sort of array_intersect() or array_merge()... the main point is to grab the matching elements and combine both elements from both arrays into one so I can do some post processing calculations...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
Which i got the matched items, but only displaying the elements from the first array... I want to combine the two arrays but only showing the matched items from "Product Category"/"Content Category", and I will need the Items Sold from array A, and Sessions from array B, so I can calculate items sold/sessions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer of my question..

```
// loop through ARRAY A
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrA); $i++) {

    //loop through ARRAYB

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arrB); $j++) {

        // if arrA value 0 matches arrB value 0
        if ($arrA[$i][0] == $arrB[$j][0]) {
            //append arrB to arrA
            $arrA[$i] = array_merge($arrA[$i], $arrB[$j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

//clean out items

for ($i = (count($arrA)-1); $i >= 0 ; $i--) {

    if (count($arrA[$i]) < 16) {
        unset($arrA[$i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the array you asked for:

```
$result = array(
    array_merge($A[0], $B[0]), 
    array_merge($A[1], $B[1])
);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! I'd like it to look to see if the "OVERALL" matches from each array, then only combine those matching elements... 
(there are much more items in this array)

Comment: I don't know what that means. I don't see anything "matching" between your two arrays at all.

Comment: I want to combine the "OVERALL" in Array A, and "OVERALL" in Array B.  If that part of both arrays match, which many of them will in the full array, I want to combine them into one and only show those that will have the same value from a[1][0] and b[1][0]. Hope that makes some sense.. 
Thanks for all the assistance1